# Where is the possible location of Engineer's sacrifice scene?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

Is this scene happening on Earth? I mean, perhaps this scene was made completely with CG effects. But if not, which waterfall looks like that? Please, answer with images and sources.

[image: credits scene with waterfall]
[image: character looking at a pit]

Comment: Possible, this is Niagara Falls, but is there any evidence to prove that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### It was *filmed* at Dettifoss.

Scott used [Dettifoss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dettifoss), in Iceland, as the [filming location](https://www.atlasofwonders.com/2012/06/prometheus-film-locations.html) for the scene (many thanks to [@Paul D. Waite](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/440/paul-d-waite) for the link). The links provided show that very little except the spaceship was changed in post-production.

### But its location in the fiction of the story is deliberately undetermined.

From [this movies.com interview](http://www.movies.com/movie-news/ridley-scott-prometheus-interview/8232) with Ridley Scott:

> **Movies.com:** That is our planet, right?
>
> **RS:** No, it doesn’t have to be. That could be anywhere. That could be a planet anywhere. All he’s doing is acting as a gardener in space.

So it could be Earth, but it might not be, and it doesn't matter to Scott or the story; that scene exists as a generic representative of a process which occurred on an unknown-but-large number of worlds (including Earth) in much the same way.

And it's certainly not *meant* to be Dettifoss, Niagara, or any of the world's other current waterfalls. 3.5 to 4 billion years ago --roughly when [life first showed up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenesis) on Earth-- Niagara Falls didn't exist (it was first [dug out by glaciation 10,000 years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niagara_Falls#Geology)), and [neither did the crust](https://xkcd.com/1194/) on which all of our modern waterfalls sit.

Comment: Regarding Dettifoss: as Wikipedia mentions, you’re quite right — [that’s where they filmed the waterfall scenes](http://www.atlasofwonders.com/2012/06/prometheus-film-locations.html).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Wow, I was just skimming through photos and moving too fast to read the words. Thanks, I'll edit that in.

Comment: Dettifoss is exact answer. The part about "anywhere" is implied, so it's better to move it in comment.

Comment: @yakunins Sorry, I thought that since you were asking which *planet* the waterfall was on, you were primarily concerned with in-film locations rather than real-life filming locations (which you only mentioned in your own comment to the question).

Comment: @BESW I thought on a chance that the whole scene is 3D-fiction, even if it looks so realistic. Anyway answer is pretty clear, thank you!